# I can't receive data in JS from my PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I've been trying receive information with AJAX,JS,JSON and PHP.
The context is the following:

I have a JS file, i sending from this file an id, that it receive a PHP file and this file makes some queries, of which the data is stored in an object and sent to a JS file to update some attributes of HTML.
I can send the id from JS to PHP correctly. Then, i've checked that i can pass the information from the queries information to an PHP object correctly too.

Here's the problem...when i receive the data in the JS file and this information pass to the **eval()** function, it give me an error.

**Notes:**

- When I take out the eval function, I can't access the attributes, because it declares  as "undefined".
- It's strange, but when I print the argument "datos" (with alert ()) displays all the information requested correctly.
- I don't speak english very well, excuse me my syntactic and semantic errors.

**infoAction.php**

```
<?php
  include 'sitioTuristico.php';

    $id = $_GET['id'];

    $sitio = new sitioTuristico("SI01");

    if($sitio->getID_SI()=="INEX"){
      print "The place doesn't exist";
      exit;
    }

    $response = new stdClass();

    $response->ID_SI = $sitio->getID_SI();
    $response->URL = $sitio->getURLS();
    $response->Nombre = $sitio->getNombre();
    $response->Descripcion = $sitio->getDescripcion();
    $response->Promedio_nota = $sitio->getPromedio_Nota();
    $response->Nombre_Cat = $sitio->getNombre_Cat();
    $response->Nombre_Ciu = $sitio->getNombre_Ciu();


/* i tried this way too
    $arr =    array('ID_SI' => $sitio->getID_SI(),
                    'URL' => $sitio->getURLS(),
                    'Nombre'=> $sitio->getNombre(),
                    'Descripcion'=> $sitio->getDescripcion(),
                    'Promedio_nota'=> $sitio->getPromedio_Nota(),
                    'Nombre_Cat' => $sitio->getNombre_Cat(),
                    'Nombre_Ciu' => $sitio->getNombre_Ciu());
*/
    echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

**info-turistica-info.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "php/indexAction.php",
    data: { id:loadData() },
    async: true,
    success: function(datos){

        var dataJson = eval(datos); **//here throws an error**
        alert(datos); **//It print all the information correctly**
        alert(datos.ID_SI); **//It print "undefined"**

        $('img[name=imagenPrincipal]').attr("src",dataJson[i].URL[0]);
        $('img[name=imagenPrincipal]').attr("id",dataJson[i].ID_SI);

    },
```

Comment: Instead of `var dataJson = eval(datos);` try `var dataJson = JSON.parse(datos);`

Comment: also i tried, it didn't work. But, with JSON.parse(), how i access to the JSON attributes?

Comment: Just do a console.log(dataJson) after running the JSON.parse() and look at the output. Post an example here, perhaps, if you don't get how to access the attributes.

Comment: "didn't work" isn't helpful at all. `JSON.parse` turns the JSON formatted string sent by your php script back into a JS object.

Answer (score 1):

First, use `JSON.parse(datos);`  instead of `eval`.
Secondly, You need to use something like this:

```
   $('img[name=imagenPrincipal]').prop("src",dataJson.URL);
   $('img[name=imagenPrincipal]').prop("id",dataJson.ID_SI);
```

Comment: yes, i did, but in JSON.parse(datos) throws the error: 

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (http://localhost/Pyto/Sistema/js/info-turistica-info.js:10:29)`

i don't know what it's mean, but it could be because I'm using utf-8 in my database?

Answer (score 1):

You are using dataJson[i].URL[0] and you don't even have "i" defined anywhere. Also don't ever use eval because eval === evil according to Douglas Crockford. Use JSON.parse(datos) and then do this:

```
$('img[name=imagenPrincipal]').prop("src",dataJson.URL);
$('img[name=imagenPrincipal]').prop("id",dataJson.ID_SI);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: `dataJson[i].URL[0]` i forgot to remove it, but i used in another test..JSON.parse() throws me an error: 

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (http://localhost/Pyto/Sistema/js/info-turistica-info.js:10:29)`

Why do you use **prop** instead attr?